# iOS - Swift: How to write generic function for this case?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, generic-programming

I'm using CoreData in my app. There're 4 tables in the database: User, Medicine, Schedule and Patient. For each table I need to write an Add function to add data into the database like this:

```
func addUser(email: String, password: NSData, handler: @escaping (_ status: SaveStatus, _ error: NSError?) -> Void){
    let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: DB.TABLE.USER, in: managedContext!)!
    let nurse = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext) as! User
    nurse.email = email
    nurse.password = password

    save { (status, error) in
        handler(status, error)
    }
}

func addMedicine(name: String, handler: @escaping(_ status: SaveStatus, _ error: NSError?) -> Void){
    let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: DB.TABLE.MEDICINE, in: managedContext!)!
    let medicine = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext) as! Medicine
    medicine.name = name

    save { (status, error) in
        handler(status, error)
    }
}
```

and so on ...

I want to write an generic function like this:

```
func addDataToDB<DATA>(object: DATA, handler: @escaping SaveStatusHandler){
    switch DATA {
    case DATA is LoginData:
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

I don't know what type should the LoginData be, so I can compare the DATA with it. Or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest solution for this case, since each `Entity` has a different `save` implementation, is to declare a `Saveable` protocol

```
protocol Saveable {
    associatedtype Parameters
    static var entityName: String { get }
    static var context: NSManagedContext { get }
    func setup(with parameters: Parameters)
    func save(_ handler: () -> ())
}
```

And then use this protocol as generic parameter in the `addDataToDB` function

```
func addDataToDB<T>(params: T.Parameters, _ handler: () -> ()) where T: Saveable {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: T.entityName, in: T.contenxt)!
    let object = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: T.context) as! T
    object.setup(with: params)

    object.save(handler)
}
```

`Parameters` in this case should be a `struct` for example, or a dictionary, it's completely up to you

Comment: If I want to do it my way, what's solution for it?

Comment: @HoangTrung If you want to do it in your way, you are not going to use generics at all. Just use an `Any` parameter and switch over its type...

Comment: Oh i see now, thanks. Just 1 more question, if I define a struct e.g. LoginData, how can I check if the parameter is LoginData type?

Comment: `if let loginData = param as? LogindData {}` for example @HoangTrung